# How to Set the value of a DateTime Widget

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse to write a java application.  My application includes a DateTime widget (org.eclipse.swt.widgets.datetime).  I cannot figure out the proper way to assign a default value.  I have a DateTime value of 2/1/2012.  I'm using the Calendar object to try to set the default value and I guess I just don't fully understand how it works.

I've tried

```
Calendar.getInstance().setTime(startDate);
StartDateWidget.setDate(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.DATE);
```

This just shows the current date.

And I've tried

```
Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
startCal.setTime(startDate);
StartDateWidget.setDate(startCal.YEAR, startCal.MONTH, startCal.DATE);
```

This shows an error in Eclipse about using static accessors and when I run the application, the date shows 3/5/2012.

I've check over the internet and see plenty of examples on using the DateTime widget, but I can't find any examples of setting the default value from an existing datetime value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Calendar incorrectly, you need something like:

```
Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
startDateWidget.setDate(startCal.get(Calendar.YEAR), startCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)-1, startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

and similarly for the time.

Calendar.YEAR is just a symbolic value that you can hand to `get()` and `set()`. See the [Calendar javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Umm...I think you don't want that. Shouldn't it be:

`Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
startDateWidget.setDate(startCal.get(Calendar.YEAR), startCal.get(Calendar.MONTH), startCal.get(DAY_OF_MONTH));`

?

And yes folks, the Java Calendar months are 0-based! (But the days are 1-based, so much for consistency.) The Eclipse API seems to match this little bit of idiocy, but probably that makes sense in this case.

But actually, what you really probably want is simply:

`Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
startDateWidget.setTime(startCal.getTime());`

Note, that will include the HH:MM:SS:MM fields, and if you prefer those to be zeroed the first alternative is the one you want.